# Wordpress htaccess redirect top level domain to directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I would like to redirect my Dutch website.nl to website.com/nl/

But can't seem to find the right code to do this in htaccess.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/nl/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```