# Using htaccess to redirect .nl to .com/nl

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to send users who use a country code in their adressbar to be redirected to the right subpage by using the htaccess file.

for example:
www.example.nl
redirect to:
www.example.com/nl

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this post, it is the very same issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392391/wordpress-htaccess-redirect-top-level-domain-to-directory

Comment: They're using the HTTP_HOST property but i'd like to use the HTTP_REFERER porperty. I've tried the solution of the other question but it gave me an error and my url turned out like this: http://example.nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the [GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) service [PHP] to find out the country of your visitor and then do the redirect.

```
include("geoipcity.inc");
include("geoipregionvars.php");

$gi = geoip_open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$getcountry = geoip_record_by_addr($gi,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ( $getcountry->country_code == "NL" ) {
    header('Location: www.example.com/nl');
}
```

Like this for NL Redirect